# Date formatting MongoDB, Want to remove timezone

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I want to get the blog post date, however, when I use the following, I get the following format: Fri Jan 21 2022 20:09:28 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time).

I only want, Fri Jan 21 2022

How can I do this?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const blogSchema = new Schema({  
 
  date: { 
    type: String,
    default: date
   }

}, { 
  timestamps: true
});
```

I'm then just sticking that date into my EJS file as follows

`<p class="date"><%= blog.date %></p>`

Comment: Storing date values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that. Store always proper `Date` objects. For custom and localized output use `Intl` object or library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/), [day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want an easy answer, you could just do something like this:

```
<p class="date"><%= blog.date.match(/^[a-z]{3}\s[a-z]{3}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}/i)[0] %></p>
```

or, even simpler:

```
<p class="date"><%= blog.date.slice(0,15) %></p>
```

These both assume that your date is already a string (I don't use mongo).  If it's not, a `toString()` after `blog.date` should suffice to make them work.

You could also use something like the (excellent) moment.js library for this, but that might be overkill for your use case.

Comment: Man, I get like so in deep with html/css monkey shit that I forget slice tools exist.
Thanks